# Trying to get current logged in user tasks in Nodejs and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, userid

I'm working on a project that enables the admin to assign tasks to different users, every users should only see his own tasks.

I tried doing that by using the user.id as key, when the user logs in we send a token, and that token includes the user_id and other user info, I'm trying to extract the id from that token and view tasks based on that.

Tasks Model

```
const TaksSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users',
  },
  taskName: {
    name: String,
  },
  taskDesc: {
    name: String,
  },
  dateAssigned: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  requiredDate: {
    type: Date,
  },
  completed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
});

// Export Schema
module.exports = Tasks = mongoose.model('tasks', TaksSchema);
```

User model

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['basic', 'admin'],
    default: 'basic',
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

// Export Schema
module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
```

tasks route

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const errors = {};
  Tasks.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
    .populate('user', ['name', 'avatar'])
    .then((task) => {
      if (!task) {
        errors.notask = "There's no Tasks Right Now";
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
      }
      res.json(task).catch((err) => res.status(404).json(err));
    });
});
```

When I try sending the get request from postman I get this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

For security I'm sending the Id through JWT token.
Here is the code

```
const payload = { id: user.id, name: user.name, avatar: user.avatar }; // Create jwt patload
        // Sign the token
        jwt.sign(
          payload,
          keys.secretOrKey,
          { expiresIn: 3600 },
          (err, token) => {
            res.json({ sucess: true, token: 'Bearer ' + token });
          }
        );
```

Comment: Are you decoding the jwt  in a middleware somewhere using `verify`? If so can you add that code to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first verify/decode the ID in order to receive the payload.

In the code, you are trying to access the `id` field from `user`. Actually you need to add a middleware which validates the JWT and appends the result in the `user` field.

Example :

middlewares/validateJwt.js

*Assuming you are sending JWT in the header as Bearer Token.*

```
 try{

 let token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]; // Bearer <token>
 let result = jwt.verify(token, "JWT_SECRET", options);
 req.user = result;
 next();
} catch...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API should look like

```
GET /api//users/:id
```

In that case you can use

```
req.params.id
```

as a first argument.

Comment: I'm sending the Id and all user info through JWT token with the payload.

Answer (score 0):

Pranesh A S's answer should get you going. To complete his suggestion, if you store the middleware validateJWT.js as

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const token = req.header("x-auth-token");
  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "NO token. Auth Failed" });
  }
  try {
    console.log(token);
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, "Secret key");
    req.user = decoded.user;
    next();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(401).json({ msg: "Token is not valid" });
  }
};
```

import it in your App.js file and while defining routes,

use

```
const validateJWT =require ("./middleware/validateJWT")
```

and

```
app.get("/", validateJWT, (req, res)=>{
// do stuff
})
```